# How to generate ColorfulButtons Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have used the below link to apply colors to buttons:

http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

How Should i used the above for Dynamic buttons ?
My code is :

```
int y=297;
for (int i=0; i < [phonesArray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d phone number is :%@",i,[phonesArray objectAtIndex:i]);

    UIButton *phoneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [phoneButton setTitle:[phonesArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [phoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dailPhoneNo:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    phoneButton.frame = CGRectMake( 11, y, 278, 42);
    [scrollView addSubview:phoneButton];


    y=y+60;
}
```

I did try this too:

```
ColorfulButton *phoneButton = [[ColorfulButton alloc] init]; 
[phoneButton setTitle:[phonesArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[phoneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dailPhoneNo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
phoneButton.frame = CGRectMake( 11, y, 278, 42);
[phoneButton setHighColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[phoneButton setLowColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]; 
[scrollView addSubview:phoneButton];
```

But the buttons not appearing on the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [phoneButton setTitleColor:(UIColor *) forState:(UIControlState)];   
  [phoneButton setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)];   
  [phoneButton setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *) forState:(UIControlState)];
```

Comment: NO @ganesh manoj. I dont want to set image on button.
In the link above. If i use ` IBOutlet ColorfulButton *phBtn;` and then apply `[phoneButton setHighColor:[UIColor redColor]]; [phoneButton setLowColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];` it did work. But its not working for Dynamic buttons. as i mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: This line `[phoneButton setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)];` will set the background color on whole button. While the code i used sets two colors on button. `setHighColor` sets the top half color. and `setLowColor` sets the bottom half color of button.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stumped for a long time too, but just figured it out so thought I'd publish my solution.  CIMGF's ColorfulButton class is very cool, but creating one programmatically is not easy.

I added an extra method to the ColorfulButton class to simplify the overall process.

in ColorfulButton.h

```
- (ColorfulButton *)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title tag:(NSInteger)tag;
```

in ColorfulButton.m

```
- (void)configureColors
{
    [self setHighColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setLowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
}

- (ColorfulButton *)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title tag:(NSInteger)tag
{
    self = [super init];
    self.frame = frame;
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.196 green:0.3098 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0]    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
    [self configureColors];
    [self awakeFromNib];    
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.tag = tag;

    return self;
}
```

in my calling .m program

```
ColorfulButton *button = [[ColorfulButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 50.0, 100.0, 37.0) title:@"Category" tag:888];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(setCategoriesPressed:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```